# How to know if a NSURLResponse comes from cache?

Tags: nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I set NSURLCache on a specific folder (../../Application Support/Offline so it won't be deleted randomly by the OS), then I send a NSURLRequest with NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad policy.

How can I tell that the response, handled by a class conforming to NSURLConnectionDelegate, comes from the cache or from the net?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good article here about the problem:

http://andrewmarinov.com/ioss-corenetwork-lying/

Basically, from the NSHTTPURLResponse the status code is always 200

So if you really need to know, you can check the item is in the cache before you make the request

```
NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpCacheResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)cachedResponse.response;
```

If so save the modified 'etag' or 'modified-date' header

```
NSString* etag = httpCacheResponse.allHeaderFields[@"etag"];
```

Then, in the response handler check the etag or modified-date is the same.  If so, the response was from the cache!

Comment: that's basically what I ended up doing

Comment: you can always answer your own question! Would have saved me an hour of my life ;-)